# Adding to a generic dictionary causes IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency, race-condition

I'm using a dictionary inside of some Task.

Logically I have set it up so that my Keys will never clash, though sometimes when I am adding to the dictionary I get this Exception.

```
Index was outside the bounds of the array.
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
   at Rpc.<MapIntoRpc>b__4[T](Object x) in Rpc.cs:line 113
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InvokeFuture(Object futureAsObj)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

I understand there can be concurrency issues from trying to remove or add the same Key multiple times, but I have accounted for that algorithmically.

What causes the add to sometimes fail? 
What is the best way to work around that?

Comment: Can you post the code that is causing the exception?

Comment: Are you adding to it from multiple threads? Likely a synchronization issue.

Comment: Consider to use [`ConcurrentDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) instead of trying to write corresponding thread-safe (lock-free?) code yourself...

Comment: I cant post the code that is causing the exception, but I am adding from multiple threads (tasks) and removing from multiple threads (tasks).

Comment: "I understand there can be concurrency issues from trying to remove or add the same Key multiple times".  I think there are concurrency issues for modifications (regardless of whether the keys are different).  I think only reads are thread-safe for the standard containers.

Comment: Ahh, any modification to the collection causes issues.. Got it.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You should have looked to the documentation. That what it says:

> A Dictionary can support multiple readers concurrently, as long as the collection is not modified. Even so, enumerating through a collection is intrinsically not a thread-safe procedure. In the rare case where an enumeration contends with write accesses, the collection must be locked during the entire enumeration. To allow the collection to be accessed by multiple threads for reading and writing, you must implement your own synchronization.
>   For a thread-safe alternative, see ConcurrentDictionary.

Comment: I am now using the ConcurrentDictionary. Thanks!

Answer (score 25):

Your issue is most likely synchronization. When a Dictionary is added to it sometimes needs to increase the size of the underlying structure (an array). If you are adding from multiple threads that may result in an `IndexOutOfRangeException`. You need to use locks etc. to make sure you are adding in a safe way.

Alternatively you can use a [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) which is a thread-safe collection.

Comment: Thanks @NominSim - this explaination helped imensely :) also was unaware of the ConcurrentDictionary - cheers!

Answer (score 19):

So you might think `Whatever! it will just break the one time` - but nope:

#### Important: Once the dictionary is broken it is broken!

There goes three hours of sales (until IIS recycled on a schedule) because of a dictionary added for debugging purposes that wasn't ever even being read from.

[image]

*Note:* This was running for 3.5 years before I hit this condition.

```
 private Dictionary<string, string> _debugLookup;

 _debugLookup[key] = virtualPath;
```

This wasn't even a static dictionary - it was an MVC `IViewLocationCache` that was an instance method.

Comment: Exact same thing happened to me. Sharing an `HttpClient` object in a multithreaded environment. If you need to add/remove headers (which is just a `Dictionary`)... it gets in to the state you posted above. I thought `HttpClient` was thread-safe! yeah, no.

Comment: facing the same problem but with a dictionary I can't change, I'm implementing an interface and returning the class with the dictionary. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60105094/getting-indexoutofrangeexception-in-modelclientvalidationrule